# std::ofstream::write adds characters

Tags: c++, ofstream

I am trying to write binary file using `std::ofstream::write` method. I found out, that some characters are not written as they are, for example:

```
std::ofstream in("testout");
int i =10;

in.write((const char *)(&i), sizeof(i));
in.close();

return 0;
```

will write the following into a binary file: `0d 0a 00 00 00`
Why is there additional `0d` byte appearing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You´ll have to specify `std::ofstream::binary` when opening.

Else, on Windows in textfile mode, `\n` (`0x0a`) in a program will be  converted to/from `\r\n` (`0x0d 0x0a`) when writing/reading the file.

Comment: @MarkGarcia no poems here on SO ;)

Comment: Good that it is preserved in the edit section for eternity :p But to think of a haiku when reading answer here...that alone is remarkable enough :)

Comment: You might add that binary mode alone isn't sufficient to ensure that he can reread the file.  You can't just dump memory images to disk and expect to reread them later.  (The fact that he needs a `reinterpret_cast` to do this should be a good indication that it won't work.)

Answer (score 6):

You opened the file in text mode and running on Windows. It adds the `0x0d` to `0x0a`. You need to use *binary* mode when you create the [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/) instance.

Answer (score 4):

The file is being written on a system that does text to binary translation. The value 10 (0A hex) in the lowest byte of i is being interpreted as a linefeed character (aka newline), and is being converted to a carriage return linefeed sequence (13 10 decimal, 0D 0A hex).

To solve this issue, change the first line of your code snippet as follows:

```
std::ofstream in("testout", std::ios::binary);
```

This will instruct the C++ runtime library to treat the file as binary and not perform any translation of bytes between newline and carriage return linefeed sequences.